# Is it possible to install MySQL Server along with standalone client-side software?

Tags: python, mysql, windows-installer, software-distribution

I'm writing an application for a venue that will have large-scale competitions. In order to effectively manage those competitions, multiple employees need to engage with and modify a set of data in real-time, from multiple machines in the gym. I have created a Python application which accomplishes this by communicating with a MySQL server (which allows as many instances of the application as necessary to communicate with it).

Is there a nice way to get MySQL server installed on a client machine along with this Python application (It only necessarily needs to end up on one machine)? Perhaps is there a way to wrap the installers together? Am I asking the right question? I have no experience with application distribution, and I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do u want to have decentralised servers ? Multiple Clients/Apps connecting to a single MySQL server, via API should be fine. If you still want to have decentralised servers, you will need to have Master - Master replication architecture

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It will be fine, but it would be largely preferable to not force them to install MySQL on their own and separately from my application. This is largely a problem of convenience.

Comment: If you use a centralized server, all you need to do is using your app, connect to a server side API. API will then handle the portion of connecting to MySQL server and doing read/write operations. You wont need to worry about installing MySQL clients in user systems.

Comment: You don't need to install stack-overflow server on your laptop to use stack-overflow. One stack-overflow server serves millions of people. Why do you want your clients to install servers on their computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'normal' way to do it is to have a network setup (ethernet and/or wireless) to connect many Clients (with your Python app) to a single Server (with MySQL installed).

To have the "Server" distributed among multiple machines becomes much messier.

Plan A:  One Master replicating to many Slaves -- good for scaling *reads*, but not writes.

Plan B:  Galera Cluster -- good for writing to multiple instances; repairs itself in some situations.

But if you plan on having the many clients go down a lot, you are better off having a single server that you try to keep up all the time and have a reliable network so that the clients can get to that on server.